# empty space under the drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

this is my tikz code:

```
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{110}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8, tdplot_main_coords]
            \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{75}
            \tdplotdrawarc{(0,0,\sintheta)}{\costheta}{0}{360}{}{}
            \foreach \angle in {0,15,...,360} {
                \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\angle};
                \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{1}{0}{15}{}{}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Top row.}
        \label{top_row}
\end{figure}
```

And this is the outcome.

[image]

May I kindly ask you to explain me where does that gap between drawing and caption comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines in the `\foreach` loop seem to be the problem. The excess space vanishes if they are taken out of the calculation of the bounding box (option `overlay`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{45}{110}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8, tdplot_main_coords]
            \tdplotsinandcos{\sintheta}{\costheta}{75}
            \tdplotdrawarc{(0,0,\sintheta)}{\costheta}{0}{360}{}{}
            \foreach \angle in {0,15,...,345} {
                \tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\angle};
                % Option "overlay" added:
                \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords, overlay]{(0,0,0)}{1}{0}{15}{}{}
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Top row.}
        \label{top_row}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- One line was drawn twice for angles `0` and `360`. Thus the example has removed the line for `360`.